# Implementation of SmallWorldExample

Tags: java, graph, jung

I am pretty confused on how to implement some JUNG classes. I am trying to create a graph with "KleinbergSmallWorldGenerator" but I am not really sure how to initialize properly.

My code:

```
Factory<? extends Graph<Integer, Integer>> graph_factory;
Factory<Integer> vertexFactory;
Factory<Integer> edgeFactory;

KleinbergSmallWorldGenerator<Integer,Integer> smallWorld;

public GraphView() {
    smallWorld = new KleinbergSmallWorldGenerator<Integer,Integer>(graph_factory, vertexFactory, edgeFactory, 20, 3) ;
    Graph2 = smallWorld.create();
}
```

I get  "java.lang.NullPointerException" even if I do `graph_factory.create();`

Help me understand; Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

```
static class GraphFactory implements Factory<Graph<Integer,String>> {
        public Graph<Integer,String> create() {
            return new SparseMultigraph<Integer,String>();
        }
    }

    static class VertexFactory implements Factory<Integer> {
        int a = 0;
        public Integer create() {
            return a++;
        }

    }
    static class EdgeFactory implements Factory<String> {
        char aa = 'a';
        public String create() {
            return Character.toString(aa++);
        }

    }
```

And then you call for example this

```
Graph<Integer, String>  Eppstein = new EppsteinPowerLawGenerator<Integer,String>(new GraphFactory(), new VertexFactory(), new EdgeFactory(), 100, 400, 100).create();
```

Answer (score 1):

`graph_factory`, `vertexFactory`, and `edgeFactory` are all `null` at construction time.  This is due to them using [their initial value, per the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5).

In your constructor, I would imagine you want to pass live instances of these objects instead of initializing them in your no-arg constructor.

Comment: but their only methods are create() etc. I don't know the proper architecture to use them as interface.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have access to which API you're using (Google-fu is not helping).  If these `Factory` types are interfaces, then there should be some concrete backing to them in order to instantiate them.  You would have to use that to instantiate them instead.

Comment: I am really confused with that JUNG stuff, and most questions here are on display issues

Comment: You need to initialize the factories before posing them into the generator.